# How to get default Google+ button to android app

Tags: android, google-signin, google-plus-signin

Hello I am trying to learn Google Sign In functionality in android. I did this and working fine according as expected.I'm following this tutorial. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Here it is showing default Google sign in button instead of Google+ red color button.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

[image: default sign in]

**Question**
How can I get the Google+ button as follows.
[image: goole plus sign in]

Comment: Not sure if you can get the red button since Google changed their icons and color scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the following inside [this Google's sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java), from line #67 to #78

```
        // [START customize_button]
        // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
        // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
        // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
        // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
        // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
        // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
        // difference.
        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
        // [END customize_button]
```

So, you can use the following:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))                
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: but even though the button color got changed, it does not redirect to the next intent as before. Any idea why?

Comment: The link in your question is from 2014? I think Google API has changed much now, please read its blogspot link to see if it can help http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/12/api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google.html

Comment: Thank you, I will refer the links